# Can you open a gallery of images using prettyPhoto by clicking on a single image?

Tags: jquery, image-gallery, prettyphoto

I'm trying to utilize prettyPhoto to open a gallery of images once I click on a single image.

On their demo page, I can see how this can be achieved by having a bunch of images:

```
<a href="images/fullscreen/1.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]" title="You can add caption to pictures."><img src="images/thumbnails/t_1.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="Red round shape" /></a>
<a href="images/fullscreen/2.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]"><img src="images/thumbnails/t_2.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="Nice building" /></a>
<a href="images/fullscreen/3.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]"><img src="images/thumbnails/t_3.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="Fire!" /></a>
<a href="images/fullscreen/4.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]"><img src="images/thumbnails/t_4.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="Rock climbing" /></a>
<a href="images/fullscreen/5.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]"><img src="images/thumbnails/t_5.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="Fly kite, fly!" /></a>
```

I do however need this to be a **album** style, meaning that once you click on one single image, other images are displayed inside the prettyPhoto popup.

Comment: No Answers for this ? This is difficult..!!

Comment: You Can Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

yes! I think this is not a right approach but this will help. put other images except album cover in another div and give it display none  css.

```
<a href="images/fullscreen/1.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]" title="You can add caption to pictures."><img src="images/thumbnails/t_1.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="Red round shape" /></a>
<div style="display:none;">
<a href="images/fullscreen/2.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]"><img src="images/thumbnails/t_2.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="Nice building" /></a>
<a href="images/fullscreen/3.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]"><img src="images/thumbnails/t_3.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="Fire!" /></a>
<a href="images/fullscreen/4.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]"><img src="images/thumbnails/t_4.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="Rock climbing" /></a>
<a href="images/fullscreen/5.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]"><img src="images/thumbnails/t_5.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="Fly kite, fly!" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: its not good idea all images loaded to page, page going to slower

Answer (score 0):

I Do This For slove This Problam In My Site

```
<a href="Images/1.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]">
    <img src="Images/2.jpg" />
</a>
```

and for Another Image Just Write a Tag And Set Rel To group Rel Like This

```
<a href="Images/3.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]"></a>
<a href="Images/4.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]"></a> 
<a href="Images/5.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]"></a>
```